# Flexible renaming in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, vim, rename

Say I have a folder with some files:

```
/Users/user101/Temp/rentest: ls
fi_name1.txt  fi_name2.txt  fi_name3.txt
```

I am looking for a flexible renaming method. For example if I do:

```
/Users/user101/Temp/rentest: ls | vim -
```

I get into vim:

[image]

Now how do I re-direct this back to the terminal? And moreover how would I use this in conjunction with `mv` command to batch rename files in the directory?

I know there is `rename` utility and most people will respond with just learn a bunch of `terminal` commands, but I find this a much more interesting/flexible way to get it done. Does anyone know of a method or has tried to do this before?

**EDIT**: There is a tendency on `stackexchange` to latch on to the specifics of a question. But I am not looking for answers that say "oh you did the files one by one so just use `mv`" or "oh column edit mode will only let you do one kind of change to all the files".

The point here is I don't want to look up google every time I want to add a pre-fix, post-fix or some sort of weird in-fix to a bunch of files in a directory. And it may not be *all* files either.

```
/Users/ivanabraham/Temp/rentest: ls
fi_name1.txt  fi_name2.txt  fi_name3.txt  gi_name3.txt  gi_name4.txt
```

and

```
ls | grep 'fi*' | vim -
```

for example.

Comment: if you're manually renaming each file like that then it's not batch renaming and can be achieved with simple `mv` commands

Comment: That is true..but I was envisioning something like going into [column edit mode](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/column-edit-mode-in-vi) to do it much faster (I just didn't capture it in the GIF) and usually there will be 30 files not 3.

Comment: column edit mode will be useless for names like `file1_...`, `file2_...`,... `file10_...`, `file11_...`. Actually you just need to learn how to use regex and then use it in every commands/applications that support regex including `vi`. Note that [`ls`'s result is not supposed to be piped into another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/444250)

Comment: That is not the type of answer i am looking for. Sorry.

Comment: +1 for the link though, my next stop would have been Python indeed.

Comment: With column operations in your text editor, or with an easy script like `for i in *; do echo "mv $i $i"; done > renaming.sh`, you can easily come with a text file (shell script) that contains `mv` commands. You can edit it as you please, and then execute using `sh renaming.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

[vidir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vidir) from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) seems to do what I was looking for. On a MacOS you can do:

```
brew install moreutils
```

once you have [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh) set up.

[image]

Given that someone wrote extensions/apps to do this, being able to do it from the CLI seems unlikely, but if someone manages to do so, I would be *very* interested to see how they did so.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this toolset is unmaintained, but I still use it: https://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/

Specifically:

> The qmv ("quick move") program allows file names to be edited in a text editor. The names of all files in a directory are written to a text file, which is then edited by the user. The text file is read and parsed, and the changes are applied to the files.

`qmv` can run in a number of modes, but I prefer to use it with the command line options `-fdo` which lists the destination only as one column in the editor.